# Ebay Trading API - GetOrders showing not paid orders

Tags: ebay-api

I have a call to the Trading API will the method GetOrders with status "Complete" ( which in ebay's documentation is for others with checkout and payment completed ) but it is showing orders that are not payed and on the payment method is says "CCAccpeted".

This `CCAccepeted` is not a payment and on ebay's admin section those orders are in "Awaiting payment".

How can i get only the ones that are payed?

Answer (score 2):

This is because  `OrderStatus` field, which you use in `getOrders` call returns as complete all orders that have checkpoint complete either if they are paid or not.

In this case eBay normally returns default payment value.

To check what orders are paid among the `complete` ones you will need to have a look at  node `OrderArray.Order.OrderStatus` in response. If an order is complete then is paid.

You can also check `OrderArray.Order.PaidTime` to know when an order have been paido

Comment: On [ebay documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetOrders.html) it says "Orders in a specific status: use the OrderRole filter to restrict results to Active (pending) or Completed (paid) orders. Additionally, this filter can be set to Shipped for Half.com orders." So complete are paid ones. And i checked and PaidTime has a date and AmmountPaid has the total of the order and OrderStatus says "Complete". But it is not payed.

Comment: as i told you this is controlling if checkout is completed or not, it signs as complete all order which have checkout complete. I don't know, i figured out myself because i was having your problem too!

Comment: Yes i understand what you said. The question now is if there is any way do determine if it is really paid or not?

Comment: yeah as i told you you can check either `OrderArray.Order.OrderStatus` or `OrderArray.Order.PaidTime` in response to see if order has been paid or not

Comment: Yes but on OrderStatus it says "Complete" on both paid and not paid orders, and on PaidTime it has a Date on both paid and not paid orders.

Comment: how can it have a date if it is not paid? ebay won't put date there unless order is either paid with paypal or marked as paid by you

Comment: @Fabio, I'm also seeing orders come in as "Complete" even when they are NOT paid yet. So far the "PaidTime" seems to be a possibly reliable indicator. Even though my unpaid order is showing as "Complete", it's still not showing a PaidTime (@zeroonnet, if you are using an SDK, are you sure you are not seeing the default value of the date/time object?).

Comment: @Josh this is correct, i've experienced this since i started working with ebay api a couple of years ago, as u said paid time is the only reliable field

Comment: @Fabio Thanks. Your answer suggests that you can look at Order.OrderStatus OR at PaidTime. Perhaps only the latter should be part of the answer?

Comment: @Josh i think so, i setted up my application to store paid order on the base of those fields. I know this is not the way it should be but we have to handle it

Comment: Here is an update on this behaviour - since August 2017, possibly version 1027 in the Java SDK, OrderStatus Complete no longer includes the unpaid  orders. This was a problem for me because I searched for Complete orders with a null PaidTime, so no unpaid orders were found. On changing the filter to All I was able to find the unpaid orders. I could find no information about this change in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PaymentStatus response:

More details:
https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/types/PaymentStatusCodeType.html

According to the docs: This value indicates that the buyer's payment for the order has cleared. A CheckoutStatus.eBayPaymentStatus value of 'NoPaymentFailure' and a CheckoutStatus.Status value of 'Complete' indicates that checkout is complete.